# get an error when trying to use multiple variables - TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a script that takes a report spit out by software(hot mess) and sorts it into something usable and pleasant to look at

the problem I am getting comes when I try to parse some columns and find variables and color them to a specific color to highlight key items

I get this error:

> TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not tuple

how do I make it work with Multiple Items
Works fine if I just use 1 item in the
"if cell is not None and (`'Item1'`,`'Item2'`) in `str(cell)`: `"`

```
#Color 01
rownumber = 1

for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row= sheet.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=4, values_only=True):
    rownumber += 1
    for cell in row:
      if cell is not None and ('Item1','Item2') in str(cell):   
        for row2 in sheet.iter_rows (min_row=rownumber, max_row=rownumber, min_col=1, max_col=12):
            for cell1 in row2:
              cell1.fill = color1_fill
```

I have tried it with and without the single `'`
and I have tried it with and without double `"`

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what the problem is. Could you post the full error? And maybe give a bit more info around the bit you're stuck on?

Comment: cell objects are never `None`. You need to look at their values. `if 'Item1' in cell.value`

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, you can't use `in` to test if a tuple is in a string.

It looks like you'd ned to test them individually and combine the results; *how* you combine them depends on what you are looking for (which isn't clear).  For example,

```
( ('Item1' in str(cell)) and (('Item2') in str(cell)) )
```

would only be true if *both* `Item1` and `Item2` were present; if you only care that one or the other is present, use `or` instead of `and`.

Comment: I need to look for multiple items, color each row that they exist in.
so if Item1 or Item 2 or item 3(etc) exists in Column A/B/C/D, color the whole row it is in.
It should color the row if any of the items exist in it.......ANY single item will make it color...

Comment: also, I'm getting Item variables from a Config file..and there may be 1 item, or there may be 40 items..... so it needs to not care about how many items there are and just parse them all.

Comment: Then it sounds like you need a loop.

Comment: I have never done a loop and I dont even know where to start....
have a chunk of code you suggest I start with?
              
something kind of like this?             
check for Item 1, make colors, check for item 2 make colors, check for item 3 make colors, no more items, move on to the next set of instructions?